# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get an error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found`. Are there suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Name-spacing issue. Somewhere in your code, you have `DB::`, use `\DB::`, or include `use DB;`. For future reference, include some code next time you post a question like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `use DB;` to your Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespace

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Query the DB

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'hay')->first();
```

This retrieves the first record with name hay

Answer (score 0):

1. Controllers lies in App\Http\Controllers, so use this in namespace.

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   ```
2. Then use the class  DB

   ```
   use DB;
   ```
3. Now you be able to use DB as below. It's just an example.

   ```
   class UserController extends Controller
   {
     function  index()
     {
      $users = DB::table('users')->get();
      foreach ($users as $user){
        echo $user->name;
      }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this witch i think is cleaner :

1 - Add the model to namespace:

```
use App\User;
```

2 - then you can do :

```
$users = User::get();
```

or maybe somthing like this:

```
$user = User::where('name', 'John')->first();
```